# Read from socket until \r\n in Java

Tags: java, python, sockets

I want to implement a POP3 client. I know that in POP3 protocol, each message ends with `\r\n`. I want to write a `recvuntil` method in Java, which will be able to receive a whole message at once.

It super easy in Python:

```
def recv_all_until_ver3(s, crlf):
    data = ""
    while data[-len(crlf):] != crlf:
        data += s.recv(1)
    return data
```

However, when I tried to do the same in Java:

```
class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String serverAddress = "interia.pl";
        int port = 110;

        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, port);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String answer = "";
        while (!answer.contains("\r\n")) {
            answer = input.readLine();
            System.out.println(answer);
        }
    }
}
```

It receives one message and hands instead of end itself. Is there any way to implement this method in Java? Can I just read characters one by one, instead of whole line until I find `\r\n` in my message? Thank you.

Comment: You can read single chars with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--

Answer (score 1):

The Python code reads one octet at a time, immediately appends it to `answer` and signals it's done if at the current iteration `answer` ends with `CRLF`.

The Java code hangs because `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns the line content after stripping the line termination. At this point `answer` does not contain `CRLF`, so `readLine()` is called once again, and since the stream is not closed from the other end (your program would then throw a `NullPointerException`) and you have an infinite read timeout (you would see a `SocketTimeoutException`), it hangs, forever waiting for the next line.

The correct version is

```
Socket socket = connect(); // Implement this
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "ASCII"));
scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");
String response = scanner.nextLine();
socket.close();
```

Notes:

- always set a timeout on sockets.
- you may want to account for [multiline messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2999773/315306).

Comment: OK, I tried this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b227b9907f6764bcdca3a856787a0b1f. My new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350870/imap-client-in-java-sockets-only-hangs-on-receiving. But it seems it does not work.

Comment: Noooo! You don't need to loop! It's `Scanner.nextLine()` that loops until a line termination is found. Just copy and paste and study the provided sample ;-)

Comment: Fine, but this does not work too :( https://gist.github.com/anonymous/084a6a6b66d4e7455e19802e6ae83819. Still hangs after receiving the first message. It somehow cant receive the second one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class (it accepts an `InputStream` as a constructor param ) and set the delimiter using `useDelimiter` method. to read messages that end with `\r\n`