# BufferedReader doesn't read last line

Tags: java, sockets, printing

So, I'm coding a server-client structure with Java Sockets, where the client sends a character specifying the function of the server he wants to use and then in another line a text that the server will modify. The thing is that the server reads perfectly all characters except the one for exiting, where it gets stuck on the input reading.

But here is the tricky thing: if I use `println(option)` it works, but if I use `print(option + "\r\n")` I need to write something else on the buffer or it won't work, and since it is for class, they make me use `print(option + "\r\n")`.

I'm sure the client works perfectly, so I'll leave here only the interesting part of the server:

```java
while (!opcion.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
    opcion = in.readLine();
    if (opcion.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
        out.println("VALE");
    } else if (!opcion.equalsIgnoreCase("L") && !opcion.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
        out.println("Opción inválida");
        in.readLine();
    } else {
        texto = in.readLine();
        aux = texto.split(" ");

        for (String s : aux) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                res.add(s);
            }
        }

        if (opcion.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            Collections.shuffle(res);
        }

        StringBuilder finalRes = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : res) finalRes.append(" " + s);
        out.println(finalRes.toString().substring(1));
    }
}
```

The variable `opcion` is initialized to an empty  string and `in` and `out` are the input and output buffers, which my professor gives me, so they are good.

By the way, I know I could add an if statement on the client so that if the option is "F" it sends a new line with whatever thing, but I want to do it clean if it's possible.

Comment: Have you tried sending bytes instead of a string?

Comment: it wouldnt allow me to use `print(option+"\r\n")` directly, right? Because I need to use it like that

Comment: Where do you close or flush the BufferedReader?

Comment: i close it after the client closes connection and autoFlush is activated, but anyway it doesn't even work if "F" is the first option entered while all the other options work perfectly

Comment: What about the writer on the other end? Does it need to be flushed?

Comment: both buffers autoFlush

Comment: *...I'm sure the client works perfectly...* Yet the evidence is strong that it does not.

Comment: well, it can fail on the server, and i'm positive that the fail is there, but if you have any suggestions i'll check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is having a similar problem, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318567/read-from-socket-until-r-n-in-java) is some useful information. It does not solve MY problem because of the restrictions my professor gives me, but it solves it for general purposes.